# Wrapping first non-HTML character of a paragraph with a span

Tags: jquery, html

Essentially, I'm trying to wrap the first text character of a paragraph, with a span tag. This span tag will allow me to style the first text character as a dropcap.

I'm not interested in doing the CSS of `:first-letter` as that has various limitations, particularly when the first character ISN'T a letter.

**This method is very close, but the issue is:** 
if the first element is a `span` tag, it finds the first text node AFTER that tag... so it targets the wrong character:
http://jsfiddle.net/Garconis/3kkvszLt/4/

Note:

Basically all previous jQuery solutions I've found are limited to finding only certain characters... or they strip out HTML elements within the paragraph... or they break the HTML tag if an HTML element is the first thing within the paragraph.

This one doesn't cover all the characters. Basically, I want it to work for any character, unless it's an HTML element... which I assume can be done by making sure it doesn't target a `<` character.

http://jsfiddle.net/Garconis/026xwx4u/

This seems to work, but for some reason removes the space before the first HTML element: http://jsfiddle.net/Garconis/3kkvszLt/

Comment: I don't understand exactly the problem, when should the span be applied?

Comment: The span should be applied to the first character or a paragraph. Unless the first item in the paragraph is an HTML element.

Comment: So what is not working in the second Fiddle?

Comment: "but for some reason removes the space before the first HTML element"

The space before the `<b>` tag is stripped out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work, unless anyone can find faults with it: http://jsfiddle.net/Garconis/g72a4h03/

```js
(function ($) { 

 // find each instance of your target
 $('p').each(function () {
 
  // now check if the first character is "<" character
  // if is NOT a "<" character, then continue
  if ($(this).html()[0] != "<") {
   // good, now search the contents of the first TEXT_NODE within the selector
   var node = $(this).contents().filter(function () { return this.nodeType == 3 }).first(),
    // check the start of the string (which is what the ^ is for)
    // find any white space (via the "\s")
    // and chunks of contiguous whitespace, which is what the + is for on "\s+"
    // and keep finding all instances at the start, which is what the global "/g" is for
    // and convert them into nothing
    text = node.text().replace(/^\s+/g, ''),
    // now start at the beginning (0 position) and grab the first character
    first = text.slice(0, 1);

   // if the first node isn't a TEXT_NODE, then stop here
   if (!node.length)
    return;

   // remove the text character that we grabbed
   node[0].nodeValue = text.slice(first.length);
   // now add it back, before the node we checked, with a wrapper
   node.before('<span class="fs-dropcap">' + first + '</span>');

  };
  
 });
 
})(jQuery);
```

```css
span.fs-dropcap { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<hr>
<p>&nbsp;"[yo]"This is a test <b>&nbsp; Other HTML <a href="#0;">tester</a> should not be affected by manipulations</b></p>
<hr>
<p>    This is a test <b>&nbsp; Other HTML <a href="#0;">tester</a> should not be affected by manipulations</b></p>
<hr>
<p><span>span tag here</span> This is a test <b>&nbsp; Other HTML <a href="#0;">tester</a> should not be affected by manipulations</b></p>
<hr>
<p><a href="#0">test</a> This is a test <b>Other HTML should not be affected by manipulations</b>
</p>
<hr>
<p>This is a test <b>Other HTML should not be affected by manipulations</b></p>
<hr>
<p>&nbsp; This is a test "Other HTML should not be affected by manipulations"
</p>
<hr>
<p><u>&nbsp;&nbsp;tester&nbsp;&nbsp;</u> This is a test "Other HTML should not be affected by manipulations"
</p>
```